# AWK for loop goes forever without BEGIN

Tags: awk

Without BEGIN for loop in AWK goes forever after printing numbers based on condition -

With BEGIN, as soon i's value is 5, loop ends

```
$ awk 'awk 'BEGIN { for (i = 1; i <= 5; ++i) print i }'
1
2
3
4
5
```

Without BEGIN -

```
$ awk '{ for (i = 1; i <= 5; ++i) print i }'
 -> Press enter here for output
1
2
3
4
5
-> Press enter again and printed numbers again .
1
2
3
4
5

1
2
3
4
5
^C -> control C to come out of loop
```

While I understand BEGIN block will be executed once at the beginning of the program but without begin, as soon as exit criteria is met, shouldn't command exit?

Please help understand what is happening here.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The loop does exit but the loop gets executed once per input line until the end of input is reached. Try typing control-D instead of control-C when entering input to provide that EOF indication. Change `print i` to `print NR, i` and add a `END{print "Done!"}` statement to your script to see whats happening.

Comment: it never gets completed. I kept pressing enter and loop kept going, never ended. If loop run one per input line then it will never end, is that right?

Comment: Do what I said and THINK about the output you're seeing, You provide an input line and then the loop runs and ends as soon as `5` is printed. Then you provide another input line and the loop runs (and ends) again. The process ends when the input ends.

Answer (score 1):

You are asking the wrong question.

The behavior in your **second** experiment is to be expected. You didn't specify a file name (or names) on the command line, so `awk` reads the standard input. It reads one line at a time, until it reaches the end of file (as it would do when reading from an actual file). And, it executes the rules you specified for every line; the lines being empty is irrelevant. Then: `ctrl-C` is an uncivilized way to terminate the program by brute force; the proper way is to issue `ctrl-D`, marking the end of the "file" and allowing `awk` to terminate normally.

Note the confusion, in your question, between "exiting from the loop" and "the program terminating". The loop ends when the exit condition is met, then `awk` advances to the next line in the input. In very general terms, exiting a loop that is part of the program's rules has nothing to do with the `awk` program itself terminating.

The "unexpected" behavior is in your **first** experiment. There, too, `awk` reads from the standard input; why doesn't it wait for EOF (`ctrl-D`) before exiting, even thought the BEGIN rules will, of course, only be executed once?

The answer is "because that's the specified behavior." For example: https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Using-BEGIN_002fEND.html

> If an `awk` program has only `BEGIN` rules and no other rules, then
>   the program exits after the `BEGIN` rules are run.

You may enjoy reading the footnote too:

> The original version of `awk` kept reading and ignoring input until the
>   end of the file was seen.

I'd say "the original version" was doing the "right thing", but that probably confused too many users, so the behavior was changed.

At least, this is the GNU "specified behavior"; I don't know what the POSIX standard says.

Comment: [The POSIX standard](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/awk.html) says "If an awk program consists of only actions with the pattern BEGIN, and the BEGIN action contains no getline function, awk shall exit without reading its input when the last statement in the last BEGIN action is executed."

Comment: @EdMorton - Somehow I got it stuck in my head that only the chapter on regular expressions is easily accessible. (Obviously that was wrong, thank you for pointing it out!) The only non-trivial computing experience I have is with Oracle SQL, and alas the SQL Standard is not freely available. For Unix/Linux things I will learn to refer to the POSIX standard regularly. Thanks!

Comment: yeah, I feel like years back you had to subscribe and create a login at least to view the POSIX docs but I may be misremembering and it's not true these days anyway. You're welcome.